# Place contents of IList into a label?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I'm trying to find a way to print the results of an IList into a label so I can see what exactly is being returned. I need to check the info stored in the IList in order to see if anything is amiss.

```
 IList<OrderItem> orderItems
```

If I wanted to put the contents of orderItems into a label, how would I do that? Do I need String.Join? Do I need a foreach?

Comment: Did you try `String.Join`?

Comment: What in `OrderItem` are you trying to display? Need to see what that class looks like.

Comment: Override `ToString` in your class `OrderItem`, return some concatenated string based on your properties, then call `string.Join` on your collection.

Comment: Well, you have two ideas.  Try them.  See what happens.  If you run into any problems in those attempts, post your code, and explain the problem(s) (after doing some basic research into those issues to see if you can find a solution).

Comment: I don't get it.  Why didn't you just try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest building an `IEnumerable<string>` from your order items, then turn that into a single string via [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx):

```
// This formats each item as ID:Name
var itemsAsText = orderItems.Select(item => string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.ID, item.Name));

label.Text = string.Join(", ", itemsAsText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<OrderItem> tmp = orderedItems as List<OrderItem>;
tmp.ForEach(a => this.Label1.Text += a.PropertyHere.ToString());
```

Comment: IList<T> doesn't have a ForEach method.

Comment: That'll throw if the IList<T> isn't a List<T>

Comment: well, yours will also throw if OrderItem doesn't contain a property named ID or Name... i'm going on the basis that he is using a type that he knows about when trying to display the values... ;)

Comment: Mine won't throw - it won't compile :)  This will compile but throw at runtime, potentially.  It's not reasonable to assume that any IList<T> is a List<T> - it may be one of many collection types.

Comment: i agree! :) but in his code, he specifies what <T> is, so it's no longer IList<T> but rather IList<OrderItem> ;) and then mine won't throw ;)

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv Yes, it will.  The item could be, for example an `Orderitem[]`, which implements `IList`, but is not in fact a `List`.

Comment: actually, if you do that, it won't compile... "cannot convert type OrderItem[] to GenericList<OrderItem>".... anyway, let's drop it on: i based myself on his code sample, and he specifically defined the type of IList he was using... and he declared his object as an IList directly, so the code i posted works... i've tested it.